# How to integrate Google marathi input tools in android application?

Tags: android, input, keypad

I am developing android application and i want marathi keypad in my application. Is there any way to integrate it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you can't programatically change the keyboard language.

Comment: am not sure but through programatically its not possible
setting in localisation,keyboard input language in device you may change it

Comment: Yes, Programmatically it is not at all possible, but is there any other way? Any tool or API that can be integrated?